# Mockito invokes method even after specyfing not to

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, javaparser

This is the method I need to stub:

```
 public static List<Path> getDiffedFilePaths(String repoDirectory, String relativeDirectoryPath) {
        List<Path> diffedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("git", "diff", "--name-only", relativeDirectoryPath);
            processBuilder.directory(new File(repoDirectory));
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                diffedFiles.add(Paths.get(repoDirectory, line));
            }
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return diffedFiles;
    }
```

This is how I stub it:

```
 @Test
    void testProcessCompilationUnitWithParamEnum() {
        try {
            AnnotationModifier modifier = new AnnotationModifier();
            AnnotationModifier modifierSpy = Mockito.spy(modifier);

            List<Path> mockDiffedFiles = Arrays.asList(
                    Path.of("mocked/file/path1"),
                    Path.of("mocked/file/path2")
            );

  
            Mockito.doReturn(mockDiffedFiles).when(modifierSpy).getDiffedFilePaths(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());

          // call the main method which consumes `getDiffedFilePaths`
```

The method should not even be called but it does. What might cause this issue?
The exception I get is:

*java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory ""): error=2, No such file or directory*

**Mockito version:**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: whats the mockito version you are using ? please see https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: Using 4.10, see edit

Comment: @Noshaf Tnx, static method was the issue, I just removed it now it works, will investigate why that is the issue.. If you know please put the answer for upvoting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito doesnot mock with static method .
Either Remove the static keyword from method to make mockito works OR use  approach as per https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: Tnx, also figured out powermockito could be used for that case

Comment: @EugenSunic Power Mock should be used in legacy applications where you cannot change the code which has been given to you. Often such code does not have unit/integration tests and even small change can result in bugs in application. Try mockito-inline instead